# The convolution formula for 3 distribution functions

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, convolution, cumulative-distribution-functions

I am trying to find a generalization of the convolution formula between distribution functions. In the case of 2 functions, I know that:
$$F_0*F_1\,(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}F_0(x-x_1) d\,F_1(x_1) $$
Where $d\,F_1(x_1)$ stresses the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral notation. I would like generalize to 3 functions. I can do:
$$F_0*F_1*F_2\,(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}F_0(x-x_1) d\,F_1*F_2\,(x_1) $$
Where, according to the firts equation: $F_1*F_2 \,(x_1)= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}F_0(x_1-x_2) dF_2(x_2)$. But I don't know how to find:
$$d\, F_1*F_2\,(x_1) = ? $$
to after replace on the second equation and then find my forumula.
How can I do this?

---

**Update:**

I tryed something like this. Let $f$ be the density of some distrib. function $F$, then $ dF(x) = f(x)dx$. So, we can do
$$d F_1*F_2(x_1) = f_1 * f_2 (x_1)dx_1$$
Where $f_1 * f_2 (x_1) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_1(x_1 - x_2)f_2(x_2) dx_2$. So,
\begin{align}
F_0*F_1*F_2\,(x) &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}F_0(x-x_1) d\,F_1*F_2\,(x_1)\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}F_0(x-x_1) f_1 * f_2 (x_1)dx_1\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}F_0(x-x_1) \left[\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_1(x_1 - x_2)f_2(x_2) dx_2\right] dx_1\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}F_0(x-x_1) f_1(x_1 - x_2)f_2(x_2) dx_2\right]dx_1\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}F_0(x-x_1) f_1(x_1 - x_2)f_2(x_2) dx_1\right]dx_2\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}F_0(x-x_1) f_1(x_1 - x_2) dx_1\right]f_2(x_2)dx_2\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}F_0(x-x_1) f_1(x_1 - x_2) dx_1\right]d F_2 (x_2)      
\end{align}
From here on, I don't know how to get a closed equation.

Comment: It's not a Lebesgue-Steljtes integral. What you mean by $d\,F_1(x_1)$ is $F_1(x_1)\,dx_1$. $d\,F_1(x_1)$ has a different meaning.

Comment: I think that $dF_1(x_1)$ is something like as $\mu_1(dx_1)$.  Am I wrong?

Comment: I updated the question with an attempted solution.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You already have $F_0 * F_1 * F_2(x) = \int F_0(x - y)(F_1 * F_2)(y)\,dy$. To develop this further, you could expand $(F_1 * F_2)(y) = \int F_1(y - z)F_2(z)\,dz$.

Comment: $d\,F_1$ is notation for the Steljtes measure with distribution function $F_1$, whereas you have used it to mean the measure with density $F_1$ with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Do you have some reference about $dF(x) = F(x) d(x)$ in the convolution formula?

Comment: I am reading the book Probability and Measure, Third Edition, by Patrick Bilingsley, page 266, equation (20.36). After that equation, he writes "See (17.22) for the notation $dF(x)$". Equation 17.22 is about Steljtes integral.

Comment: I don't understan  why $d F_1(x_1)$ is $F(x_1)dx_1$